# CUDA independent thread scheduling starvation

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

[This](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/inside-volta) official NVIDIA blog in the section "Starvation-Free Algorithms" claims that ITS in Volta adds support for starvation-free algorithms with a few details. [This](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/turing-tuning-guide/index.html#independent-thread-scheduling) official documentation states that Turing features the same ITS as Volta. Why does the following code experience fatal starvation?

EDIT: I modified the code to test for intrawarp starvation only. Tried it on T4, 2080 Ti and RTX 3070, with CUDA versions including 11.5 and 12.1, using appropriate arch/code parameters. Both lock implementations, `libcudacxx` and `legacy`, never allowed thread 1 to acquire the lock, except `legacy` on RTX 3070, despite the fact that the lock was released for a whole second at a time.

```cpp
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda/semaphore>
#include <cuda/atomic>

__device__ uint32_t something_very_slow(uint32_t x) {
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i / 1e7 < 1; ++i) {
    x *= 13;
    x += 1;
    x %= 123456789;
  }
  return x;
}

__device__ cuda::binary_semaphore<cuda::thread_scope_block> lock{1};
__device__ cuda::atomic<uint32_t, cuda::thread_scope_block> mask{0};
__device__ cuda::atomic<uint32_t, cuda::thread_scope_block> clobber{0};

__global__ void starvation_libcudacxx() {
  lock.acquire();
  printf("start thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
  bool cont = false;
  do {
    printf("step thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
    lock.release();
    clobber.fetch_add(something_very_slow(clobber.load()) + threadIdx.x);
    cont = mask.fetch_add(threadIdx.x) == 0;
    lock.acquire();
  } while (cont);
  printf("done: %d\n", clobber.load());
  lock.release();
}

__global__ void starvation_legacy() {
  __shared__ uint32_t lock, mask, clobber;
  if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
    lock = mask = clobber = 0;
  }
  __syncthreads();
  while (atomicCAS(&lock, 0, 1) == 1) {
  }
  printf("start thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
  bool cont = false;
  do {
    printf("step thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
    atomicExch(&lock, 0);
    atomicAdd(&clobber, something_very_slow(atomicAdd(&clobber, 0)) + threadIdx.x);
    cont = atomicAdd(&mask, threadIdx.x) == 0;
    while (atomicCAS(&lock, 0, 1) == 1) {
    }
  } while (cont);
  printf("done: %d\n", atomicAdd(&clobber, 0));
  atomicExch(&lock, 0);
}

int main() {
  starvation_libcudacxx<<<1, 2>>>();
  starvation_legacy<<<1, 2>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Comment: "Independent thread scheduling in Volta ensures that even if a thread T0 currently holds the lock for node A, another thread T1 **in the same warp** ..."

Comment: @RobertCrovella, thank you. The first paragraph of the section looks to me like it first states that "Starvation-free algorithms are .. enabled", then goes into their requirements, in terms of threads in general, not constrained to warp. The mention of same-warp threads below looks like just an example limited to the tricky part that didn't work on earlier architectures. But you should know better, and my test doesn't detect intrawarp starvation. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: switched to intrawarp starvation (again)

Answer (score -1):

First thanks to your question since I was also reading this blog recently, and your codes help me to understand the blog better.

---

Short answer: Use the **same structure** as the blog to make the codes work. And it is not a good habit to use one seemingly infinite loop in the **kernel**, this seems to be contrary to the GPU kernel design which is just one **small** thread to run.

Then starvation between **thread grids** will disappear (I use GTX 1650 which is also the Turing architecture):

```bash
$ alias nvcc
nvcc='nvcc -arch=sm_75'
$ nvcc starvation.cu
$ ./a.out 
start thread 0
...
start thread 1
...
start thread 0
...
```

So at least the Starvation-Free worse case where **only one thread** in multiple grids get the lock is avoided. But obviously this seems to be not what **independent thread scheduling** should do with finer-grained thread level.

P.S. Since I don't have other GPUs, I didn't know what the behavior is on **pre-Volta GPUs** like Pascal.

---

Here I showed how to change the codes to work partly. But why **independent thread scheduling** implemented in the hardware, the driver or others (maybe beyond the user knowledge) can't make the original codes work is beyond my abilities. So it may be not easy to know why it doesn't use finer-grained thread level to make your *original codes* work.

Hope someone like **Nvidia employee or CUDA experts** can help improving this answer. Thanks in advance.

---

Detailed answer:

After comparing your codes with original blog codes (here I posted to better view):

```cpp
__device__ void insert_after(Node *a, Node *b)
{
    Node *c;
    lock(a); lock(a->next);
    c = a->next;

    a->next = b;
    b->prev = a;

    b->next = c;
    c->prev = b;

    unlock(c); unlock(a);
}
```

The blog kernel puts `unlock` as the final instruction. So change your codes to be the same structure as the blog:

```
$ diff starvation_orig.cu starvation.cu     
--- starvation_orig.cu  2023-08-02 15:38:42.592480115 +0800
+++ starvation.cu       2023-08-02 15:39:14.219905308 +0800
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+// https://stackoverflow.com/q/76497234/21294350
 #include <cuda.h>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <cuda/semaphore>
@@ -20,15 +21,12 @@
   lock.acquire();
   printf("start thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
   bool cont = false;
-  do {
-    printf("step thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
-    lock.release();
-    clobber.fetch_add(something_very_slow(clobber.load()) + threadIdx.x);
-    cont = mask.fetch_add(threadIdx.x) == 0;
-    lock.acquire();
-  } while (cont);
-  printf("done: %d\n", clobber.load());
+  printf("step thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
   lock.release();
+  printf("release lock\n");
+  clobber.fetch_add(something_very_slow(clobber.load()) + threadIdx.x,cuda::memory_order_seq_cst);
+  cont = mask.fetch_add(threadIdx.x) == 0;
+  printf("done: %d\n", clobber.load());
 }
 
 __global__ void starvation_legacy() {
@@ -39,10 +37,10 @@
   __syncthreads();
   while (atomicCAS(&lock, 0, 1) == 1) {
   }
-  printf("start thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
+  printf("starvation_legacy start thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
   bool cont = false;
   do {
-    printf("step thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
+    printf("starvation_legacy step thread %d\n", threadIdx.x);
     atomicExch(&lock, 0);
     atomicAdd(&clobber, something_very_slow(atomicAdd(&clobber, 0)) + threadIdx.x);
     cont = atomicAdd(&mask, threadIdx.x) == 0;
@@ -54,7 +52,7 @@
 }
 
 int main() {
-  starvation_libcudacxx<<<1, 2>>>();
-  starvation_legacy<<<1, 2>>>();
-  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
+  while (1) {
+    starvation_libcudacxx<<<1, 2>>>();
+  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer. However my question was not how to make this synthetic example work. It was carefully constructed to *not* work contrary to the documentation. My goal was to understand why, in order to write robust code without testing it in every scenario on every targeted device. I've submitted a bug report a month ago; it was verified, but I don't know anything further -- whether it is a code generation bug in NVCC, a documentation deficiency, my own misunderstanding or something else.

Comment: @maxplus Fine. As my answer says, maybe only Nvidia employees or CUDA experts can answer your question about why ITS failed with your specific example. Could you post the bug report link here?

Comment: No. As someone mentioned elsewhere, "Only the bug filer and relevant NVIDIA personnel have access to a bug report and can check its status."

Comment: Fine. Wait for NVIDIA future updates of its products.